# How to report an error spotted on a RFC to the IETF

Tags: rfc

I noted an error in a RFC and I would like to report that error and, I hope, to see an Errata issued.

Does anyone know how to officially report an error to the IETF Working Group. Is there a sort of bug/typo tracking at the IETF?

I tried to send an email to the author of the RFC, but I have not received any answer and I am not sure my email has been taken into account.

Comment: I don't think this question is on topic on StackOverflow. It seems like you are asking for an external resource (a bug tracking system for RFCs).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: Agreed. I also voted for its closure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can report an errata :

> The RFC Editor database maintains a list of errata for each RFC. To
>   search for errata on a particular RFC, or to report new errata, please
>   visit the [RFC Editor Errata Page](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata.php).

*https://www.ietf.org/rfc.html*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.